# Is my opponents card order the same for me as for him?

Tags: hearthstone

For tactical reasons it would be helpful to know, if my opponent sees his cards in the same positions as I see his card backs. Can I rely on what hearthstone shows me, or is it just animation?

Examples:

1. It's my opponents turn and he is thinking about playing a card, so I can see a card back highlighted. If he plays that card, is it the same he was looking at? If he doesn't play that card, but changes his mind and plays another card instead, and later in the game I see him playing the card which was highlighted before, is it the same card he was looking at some turns before?
2. The opponent is thinking and after some time he decides to obviously waste a card in order to give him a card draw. The new card is sorted to the right-most position in his hand (from my view). If he plays that card, is it the same, which he just drew? Or if he plays another card, will the card he drew remain in this position of his hand?

Knowing this would give some insight of his tactics and it would be possible to get some ideas what his deck relies on and which cards he is possibly waiting/expecting/hoping for to draw.

Depending on the answers it might be advisable to change oneselves behaviour when thinking about which card to play and not move the mouse above the card.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, the cards in your opponents hand are in a fixed order. They are sorted by the time he/she drew them, with the leftmost card being the oldest. If you pay attention you can determine which turn the played card was drawn. There are a couple of tools that can help you with this such as [Decktracker](https://github.com/Epix37/Hearthstone-Deck-Tracker/), which shows you which turn each card in your opponents hand was drawn.

Comment: Note, I would recommend avoiding Decktracker for now, since its in a grey area as far as cheating goes. It's not difficult to tell which card was drawn when anyways.

Comment: @Waterseas: Can you give any source to why Decktracker is considered as cheating by blizzard?

Comment: @Zaibis Because it is an external program designed to give the player an advantage.

Comment: @Waterseas: I don't take this serious since Hearthstone lead designer ben brode explicitly anounced blizzard is fine with tracking software(https://twitter.com/bdbrode/status/511151446038179840). All else I was able to see is rumor and refference to sources where I have no acces without creating a twitter account. And serious... if HS lead designer anounces on twitter publicly that this software is fine wihtout (even after requests about it) recalling this claim. Then Blizzad has to anounce it more publicly then just in an restricted tweet I can't even access.

Comment: So if you can't bring up a reasonable source supporting your claim, I see nothing in, but hot air.

Comment: @Zaibis A. Ben Brode isn't in charge of determining who gets banned and who doesn't. B. The support I used was logic. C. Community Manager says otherwise: http://eu.battle.net/hearthstone/en/forum/topic/14381349581#9

Comment: @Zaibis Its your choice if you want to risk it, but don't deceive others into thinking that blizzard is perfectly okay with it.

Comment: @Waterseas: thats exactly the post i mentioned. Community manager just comments on something someone posted on twitter what I cant even acess. So you are refering to the same kind of information as I do but mine is public accessable while the one which is claimed to be not accepting it isnt even accessable for anyone. So before saying the sources i present are deveiveing some one into something, show me an public accessable source that disproofs my sources....

Comment: @Zaibis What...? How is the one that I just linked not publicly accessible? It can be viewed by anyone; that's the definition of publicly accessible.

Comment: @Waterseas: Yeah and if I click it it tells me I can't see it if I don't sign up and follow the person who posted it. What I'm not willing to do. So it is not publicly accessable. and thats also why I don't take it serious if anyone is refering to it... before there isn't any oficcial statement about it publicly accassable!

Comment: @Zaibis You having technical issues isn't the same as not publicly accessable. I can view the comment just fine without doing so. Also, not sure what you're referencing even, since 'following' someone isn't actually a thing on the hearthstone forums.

Comment: @Zaibis Unless you're referencing the linked twitter in the comment, which is irrelevant, since that's not what I'm referencing.

Comment: @Waterseas: I'm talking about the tweet of the dude takralus is refering to. The Community manager is just refering to a tweet without any explanation. this tweet is not publicly accessable (and this is not due to any technical problems) and as long just every one is refering to this tweet it isn't an official statement by any means. Also community Managers statement isn't to be taken as the last word.... I have even seen CM's statements contradicting. and the linked post isn't even a real statement but just a refference to an non public refference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36517/discussion-between-zaibis-and-waterseas).